# How to customize input typewriter

Tags: css

I want to hide the typewriter (this blinking | mark) from my input, is there any way to do it using CSS?

```
input {
   some css proerty to hide the typewriter
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes u can do it by using.Just make sure to adjust the other styling properties of your input field as needed to ensure it looks the way you want it to without the cursor being visible.

```
   input {
   caret-color: transparent; /* Hide the blinking cursor */
     }
```